# Overriding onMeasure method within view

Tags: android, android-layout

I am currently overriding the `onMeasure()` method within a custom view in order to ensure it's width and height are equal and everithing appears to work except the parent `linearlayout` appears to think its dimensions haven't changed. I am currently using the `setMeasuredDimension()` method within the `onMeasure` override, in order to force the width to the measured height. Is there something else I need to do in order for the parent `viewgroup`to see these  changes. Please note that the view  is drawn at the  correct size, but the parent view group now extends past the screen (it's not seeing the new width set from within the `onMeasure()` override).

As requested, I have pasted my onMeasure() code below:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec,heightMeasureSpec);
    int measuredHeight=getMeasuredHeight();
    setMeasuredDimension(measuredHeight,measuredHeight);

    if(measuredHeight > m_iconType.largestDimension()){
        m_iconType.largestDimension(measuredHeight);
        try {
            Class<?>clazz = Class.forName(m_iconType.iconClassName());
            Constructor<?> constructor = clazz.getConstructor(Integer.TYPE);
            m_iconType.icon((CachedBoardElement)constructor.newInstance(measuredHeight));
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Just to clarify, CachedBoardElement is a bitmap cached vector canvas whose maximum dimension is set during construction; it has to be recreated if view exceeds the current maximum.

Comment: Please post your onMeasure() code. Also, is this a custom view, are do you just want to make the width and height equal?

Comment: As requested, I have posted my onMeasure() code above. This is part of a custom view that renders one of several selectable vector icons (for use in a ListView).